# Running test packages automatically from a central pkg

Tags: go

I have a tests directory containing several tests packages. I want to see if I am able to have a central main_test.go file which executes all tests packages internally?

This way I would be able to treat all packages as unified and be able to get a unified coverage report etc, without being worried about test setup or without adding any bash scripting etc.

Comment: It's possible to have a central package run tests in other packages, just keep in mind that you cannot import code that's declared in `_test.go` files, so to get around that, your "several test packages" will have to declare the test code in non-test files.

Comment: You mean they are not invoked as regular tests?

Comment: Something like this can be hacked together. But it's terribly ugly. There are some clues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601236/run-tests-programmatically-in-go

But in general, it's a nightmare to do this (I know because I've done something very similar, and regret it).  Better to use the tools as intended.

Comment: A better approach is probably something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839543/no-test-coverage-when-tests-are-in-a-different-package

Comment: It seems there is no idiomatic way of running multiple test packages. Even if I use script, it will not be accurate in terms of code coverage. Because each produce their own code coverage and thus they will have overlapping coverage report which cannot be summed together.